# How do I grab a Blogspot background image?

Tags: blogger

I saw a Blogspot blog where a user had a custom background that I would like to get a hold of for personal use.

Although the picture does not seem to mention any copyright information, my only intention is to use it as my personal desktop wallpaper, and not to distribute it or upload it anywhere else on the internet.

How do I go about downloading or saving the image for my own use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by investigating how it is that particular page is using that image.  Depending on the browser, you can do this in a variety of ways.

In Internet Explorer, you can right-click the background and select `Copy Background` or `Save Background as...` (if it is actually a background image, otherwise there should be `Save Image as...`).

In Firefox, you can `View Background Image` and save if it's a background image, or `View Image` and save if it isn't.

There should be options like this for each browser, with verbiage and exact options varying by version.  If not, you'll need to view the CSS or HTML and find the actual URL of the image, as descibed [here](http://css-tricks.com/264-how-to-steal-a-websites-background-image/).  Again, by browser you will be provided with a variety of options in doing this (IE's Web Developer option, numerous extensions for Firefox, Chrome's Developer Tools, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I was using chrome that showed no options on right click. The firefox solution worked.